# A soft question on inequalities of any non-negative RV

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, random-variables

Hope this isn't  a duplicate.

For any non-negative RV X, I was trying to show that,$$E (X) + E ({\frac{1}{X}}) \geq 2$$ and $$ E (\text{ max }({X, \frac{1}{X}})) \geq 1$$

Just know the well-knowned inequalities but cannot come up with any idea. Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Because, for every positive $x$, $$x+\frac1x\geqslant2\qquad\max\left(x,\frac1x\right)\geqslant1$$

Comment: @Did is it that simple?

Comment: It is. (But why did you delete your other question?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming here that $X$ is strictly positive, I think. If so, you can start with $\mathbb{E}[(\sqrt{X}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{X}})^{2}] \geq 0$ and expand the brackets!

As for the second, you can see that if $X \geq 1 $ then $0<\frac{1}{X} \leq 1$ and if ${X} \leq 1$ then $\frac{1}{X} \geq 1$.  So max($X,\frac{1}{X}) \geq 1$

Answer (score 0):

$$X+\frac1X\geq 2 \implies \mathbb E(X+\frac1X)\geq 2 \implies \mathbb E(X)+\mathbb E(\frac1X)\geq 2$$

$$max(X,\frac1X)\geq 1 \implies \mathbb E(max(X,\frac1X))\geq 1.$$